# Android service with u10_system user id

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

This is under Android Kitkat/Lollipop with multiple account feature enabled. I created a service with the user id "system", and had an activity binding to the service. Then in different user account, I tried to have another activity binding to the same service (with the flag Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE). I was hoping that the activity would be bound to the existing service with the user id "system". However, Android created a new service with the user id "u10_system". Why would this happen? Is it possible to bind to the existing service whose user id is "system"?

Edit: For the service, I had this attribute: android:singleUser="true". The service also has INTERACT_ACCROSS_USERS permission.

Comment: I tried this on Android L and it had the same problem.

Comment: Note that "system" and "u10_system" have different privilege. "u10_system" does not have system privilege. That is why I asked the question.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue in android 11. Is this issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

What you see is the effect of a combination of `sharedUserId` and `singleUser` flags in AndroidManifest.xml. This is what I found to happen in Android 12 (so ~8y later, things might have been different in Lollipop...):

- `sharedUserId:system` && `singleUser:true`

  - runs as linux user "system" uid 1000 aka Android user 0
  - singleton and priviledged
- `sharedUserId:system`

  - runs as "u10_system"
  - not singleton but priviledged
- `singleUser:true`

  - runs as linux user "u0_a222" (or another _a number)
  - singleton but not priviledged
- none

  - runs for each normal user
  - not singleton, not priviledged